# How to convert UInt16 value to UInt32?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to convert `Uint16` to `UInt32`. How to convert `UInt16` value to `UInt32` in C#?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your effort first please! Read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: The better question is why are you using these types in the first place. They should only even really be used over Int32 if you're interacting with some non-.NET dll.

Answer (score 8):

You don't have to convert it, `UInt32` can accommodate `UInt16` so just simply assign it.

```
UInt16 number = 20;
UInt32 newNumber = number;
Console.WriteLine("Number: {0}, New Number: {1}",number,newNumber);
```

Output:

```
Number: 20, New Number: 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert from big range to small range is allowed by implicit cast.
Just assign UInt16 to UInt32.